# Mapping subdomain to GCP app engine with wildcard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ovh

I'd like to map my_domain_name and any subdomain of my_domain_name name to the same App Engine ("backend") in Google Cloud platform.

I follow the step of this documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains

I deployed this dispatch.yaml

```
- url: "my_domain_name.com/*"
 service: backend
- url: "*.my_domain_name.com/*"
 service: backend
```

Settings/Custom domains looks like this :
Custom domain name

.my_domain_name.com/* (SSL Security : Google-managed, auto-renewing)
*.my_domain_name.com/* (SSL Security : None)

And I've filled appropriate CNAME, A, and AAAA records on my registrar (OVH).

It works on my_domain_name.com, but on xxxxxx.my_domain_name.com, I got a security "Failure in secure connexion error". Is it related to SSL security ? How can I fix that ?

Comment: What type of SSL certificate? Your question states `Google-managed`, but Google Managed SSL certificates **do not support** wildcards. Edit your question with more details.

Comment: What does this mean: `*.my_domain_name.com/* (SSL Security : None)`?

Comment: Oops the table did not work in stackoverflow rendering, that could not help to be understandable. I did NOT add any SSL certificate, just wrote here what I can see on column SSL Security of "Custom domains" panel.

Comment: ANd *.my_domain_name.com is/* is the custom domain name

Comment: Without an SSL certificate, HTTPS will fail. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: In order to deploy an SSL **Wildcard** certificate, you will need to either purchase one or use a service such as Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I'll purchase one.